# Htaccess rewrite if not path entered

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I would like the webapp/index.php loaded whenever any path/page is requested for. Therefore I put the following in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /webapp/index.php?_path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This work for any path, although is no page is given, it does not seem to work. How can I have the same rule applied when "/" is requested for ?

Comment: Can we talk *(if your problem is still unsolved)*: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28210/servant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
RewriteRule ^($|.*) /webapp/index.php?_path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or you may try this in case the .htaccess file is not at root or DirectoryIndex is not set:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^($|.*)          [NC]
RewriteRule .* /webapp/index.php?_path=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: url1: domain.com (does not work); 
url2: domain.com/randomword (works)

Comment: Where is the htaccess file? Should be at root. Make sure the browser's cache is cleared before any test.

Comment: Updated my answer with one additional directive.

Comment: Thanks ! I updated DirectoryIndex to "/webapp/index.php". It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.+` (one or more characters) by `.*` (0 or more characters). i.e.:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webapp/index.php?_path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm. Don't think its working yet. I changed it to "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webapp/index.php?_path=$1 [L,QSA]"
Still does not work, just displays the directory structure